# Receive HTTP request in one Python process, reply from another

Tags: python, events, io, response, multiprocessing

Can I "move" response object somehow from one process to another?

The first process is a non-blocking server which does some other IO. It needs to be done in a non-blocking environment like Tornado or Twisted or something like this.

Another process (actually, a pool of "worker" processes) is needed to process images with PIL. I can't do it in threads because of GIL. However, either the worker needs to get a file-handle of response object to write the result to, or it should return the result back to the first process, and since the result can be pretty huge (~1 mb), it does not seem like a good idea. (It's probably going to be a separate pool of processes, not a fork for every request - the latter one seems like a bad strategy)

So, can I somehow allow the worker process to write to the response directly?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not write to actual file, and read from it in response handler? Then you only need to pass to image processor file path.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more natural to have different threads/processes serve different requests, from start to finish?

Comment: @NicolaMusatti because Image processing seem to be blocking IO all the time

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff that's write+read+write while I can do just write with my scheme

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff rather than that, if everything else fails, I'd just do X-Accel-Redirect from one server process to another

Comment: Hmm. Can you just replace `stdout` for a process maybe? (Although after quick searching it seems you can't.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Only one process can have access to one port at one time and you cannot respond directly without accessing the port.

But you don't need that. What you need is **proxy**! You can add a thread to your app which will listen on a different port. Then you fire your image process and when that process finishes its work you can send the result to the port. Then you're thread will read it and send the response.